# Why I can't use async.waterfall like this

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I need to write unit tests for functions used in waterfall so it is necessary that they have body defined outside waterfall, but below (trial) code is not able to run, Is there anything I'm missing ?

```
async.waterfall([ 
    one(cb),
    two(cb)
  ],function(){});

var function one(cb){cb(null)}
var function one(cb){cb(null)}
```

Comment: Hi guy, read more in: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

Answer (score 0):

Just write the functions as variables and reference them:

```
var one = function (cb) {console.log('1'); cb(null); }
var two = function (cb) {console.log('2'); cb(null); }

async.waterfall([ 
    one,
    two
  ], function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
async.waterfall([ 
    one,
    two,
  ], function (err, result) {
     // result now equals null
});

function one(cb) {
    cb(null, null);
}

function two(arg1, cb) {
    cb(null, arg1);
}
```

And try it with demo:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

// Or, with named functions:

```
async.waterfall([
    myFirstFunction,
    mySecondFunction,
    myLastFunction,
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
function myFirstFunction(callback) {
    callback(null, 'one', 'two');
}
function mySecondFunction(arg1, arg2, callback) {
    // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
    callback(null, 'three');
}
function myLastFunction(arg1, callback) {
    // arg1 now equals 'three'
    callback(null, 'done');
}
```

And read more into [Link](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html)